# Akka and persistence

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I use Akka.Net in my pet project. I've heard a lot about actor model and finally have a chance to play with it. First thing I was surprised of is that persistence is not a basic functionality, it is kind of "plugin". Now I ran into situation I didn't understand. Let's say I have an API and all external commands are routed to Supervisor actor. While processing those commands this actor creates child actors and routes commands to them. That's the way I learned from books. Now let's say Supervisor created to children: A and B and they have ActorRef to each other. I want to use Context.SetReceiveTimeout to free memory occupied by 'idling' actors, because I may have millions of them in total. So, imagine actor B decides it's time to 'passivate' or remove itself from memory. I'm using Akka.Persistence, so everything is stored somewhere in form of messages (events) or snapshots. So actor be kills itself by PoisonPill. The problem is that in Actor's lifecycle there is no state like 'removed-from-memory'. So from Supervisor point of view, now it has only one children, actor A. And if actor A sends message to actor B via owned ActorRef, it goes nowhere.

I ran into this situation first time when I tried to gracefully restart my service. I found that after restart Supervisor actor knows nothing about it's children A and B. But if it tries to recreated them, then and only then they're restored from storage because PersistenceId kept the same.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. As I said before, for me it looks like that persistence wasn't meant from Day 0. If I were designing such thing as Actor framework, I would think it is responsibility of framework to hide differences between actor existing and in memory and actor existing but swapped to storage. It is very similar to page fault with virtual memory!

Comment: I'd probably avoid passing that `ActorRef` into the child actors. Instead, you could send a message to parent actor which will use some logic to forward it to other child actor. Like, parent actor could check whether potentially "dead" actor exists in its context before it forwards the message.

Comment: @BranislavLazic that's the way I'm trying to solve one of the problems - route all communications between A and B via their parent. But it doesn't solve the problem of restarting service, where after restart Supervisor doesn't know about its children. Of course I can store they ids in Supervisor' state and "re-create" them after recover, but it leads to the situation when all children (there can be million of them) are loaded from storage to memory. And this is exactly the situation I want to avoid. I want to have million actors, but keep only "hot" ones in the memory.

Comment: And why not recreating them when needed? Do you have any unique identifier for your child actors that comes from outside? For example, if the message with id is sent to Supervisor, you can check whether the child actor with provided id (unique identifier that comes from outside) exists in context of Supervisor. If not, create it in the context of Supervisor and if it's persistent, it will recover its state.

Comment: @BranislavLazic well, that is maybe possible solution, but... If this is right way to do, then why it is not written in CAPS in every book or blog article like "You should NEVER use ActorRef to communicate with another actor!"? Because what it means is you always have to pass the message to your parent and provide an target actor's path, not ActorRef. And actor's parent will do the same and delegate it to it's parent and so forth until it reaches top most actor which starts re-creating actors mentioned in target path.

Comment: Because it's not an issue. E.g. I could have an actor for HTTP server which takes few other actors (like some actors for querying database) to send them a messages from itself. It's not mandatory that child actors should communicate via parent. However, I'd need a good supervision strategy to decide what to do in case if HTTP server actor fails or one of query actors. Your case is specific. Simply, you have to decide what to do with A actor if B fails.

Comment: @BranislavLazic that's what I'm talking about - persistence is not a part of Akka core framework. Imho, I shouldn't care is my actor sitting in memory whole lifecycle, or it is just loaded from storage. If, for example, it has 2 children before being 'passivate', it should have exact same number after being loaded back to memory from storage without my (as developer) involvment in this process.